# How to recover errors generated by mysql in the log file?

Tags: mysql

I don't understand why console-generated errors in mysql are not showing up in the logs.

My question is : How can I recover the errors generated with mysql in the log file?

Comment: Provide example (of code) what are you trying so far?

Comment: @Gander How would it be possible to create a code example for how an error in the console isn't getting logged by MySQL? Do you need just any SQL with a syntax error to be able to Answer this post?

Answer (score 1):

When MySQL generate error, if the error is in a user session - it will redirect it by default to the console or to the remote session handler in case this is a network session.

When the MySQL server internally catches errors which are not generated by user session, they will normally be logged to the error log.

You can of course customize the error logging, use this link for further reading:
       https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-log.html